# How to determine if the Windows 7 Desktop has an ActiveWindow

Tags: delphi

Is there a way to determine if the desktop has a foreground window?

This works but it seems incorrect?
When there are no foreground windows on my desktop handle returns 328992.

```
Handle := GetForegroundWindow;
if Handle = 328992 then
begin
  MessageBox(0, 'There is no active window.', 'No Active Window',   MB_ICONWARNING or MB_OK);
  exit;
end;
```

What is the best way to accomplish this?
Delphi 2010

Followup:

```
iDesktopWindow := GetDesktopWindow;
iShellWindow := GetShellWindow;
iForegroundWindow := GetForegroundWindow;
ShowMessage('DesktopWindow: ' + IntToStr(iDesktopWindow));
ShowMessage('ShellWindow: ' + IntToStr(iShellWindow));
ShowMessage('ForegroundWindow: ' + IntToStr(iForegroundWindow));
```

DesktopWindow returns 65552 
ShellWindow returns 65864
ForegroundWindow returns 65724

My previous edit showed a different value for ForegroundWindow each time the app was run, but I failed to minimise the application before getting the value.  Now I am getting a consistent value of 65724 for ForegroundWindow each time.  In this case there are no active windows... just the desktop and minimised windows.

Comment: Please define "active window" as distinct from "foreground window." What are you talking about?

Comment: Sorry... I edited it to change active window to ForegroundWindow.
All I need to do is to determine if the desktop does not have any window... just the desktop.  My tesing session has the desktop and two minimized applications.

Comment: If you click on the desktop then you will see that the ShellWindow becomes active. If you just minimise everything then the foreground window is something with window class WorkerW. Did you run Spy++ yet?

Comment: I can not click on the desktop because the method attempts to screen capture a window or window client. In this case if there is no foreground window I want to abort the window screen capture. I did not mention this because I thought it would complicate the issue.  I do not have Spy++.  Where you you get it?

Comment: http://mdb-blog.blogspot.co.uk/2010/11/microsoft-spy-or-spyxx-for-download.html  but it comes with Visual Studio which is where I got it. There is also WinSpector and a host of other tools.

Answer (score 2):

There's always a foreground window. Well, there are instants when the foreground window is being changed when `GetForegroundWindow` returns `NULL`, but those instants pass pretty quickly!

I expect that `328992` is the window handle for one of windows used to show the desktop. Use Spy++ or similar to work out which window it is. My guess is that the state you are trying to detect is when the [shell window](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633512.aspx) is the foreground window.

```
function GetShellWindow: HWND; stdcall external 'user32.dll';

function IsShellWindowTheForegroundWindow: Boolean;
begin
  Result := GetShellWindow=GetForegroundWindow;
end;
```